# The constructor Intent(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){}, Class<Player>) is undefined

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm getting an error stating: The constructor Intent(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){}, Class) is undefined

on the line: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);`

and I'm not sure how this can be corrected. Has anyone incountered anything like this before? I thought using an intent in this format was pretty standard.

```
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pos) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
            intent.putExtra("playlist", playlist);

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If this code is in a Activity class for example called MainActivity, you can use this

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class);`
You can reference the outer class by calling OuterClass.this

Comment: For some reason the new intent does not launch - any idea why?

Comment: @user3009687 you forgot `startActivity(intent)`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Player.class);
```